# How do I make this link perform an onclik event after loading (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, routes

I have the below link

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="xtenderSearchItem.modal_visibility = ! xtenderSearchItem.modal_visibility;">Request</a>
```

I'd like it to change the language of page (happens after reloading the page) then make the xtenderSearchItem visible as above once the link has loaded.

I have the below so far, but it makes the xtenderSearchItem visible first then loads the page/changes the language.

```
<a href="language/{{ 'zh' }}" onclick="xtenderSearchItem.modal_visibility = ! xtenderSearchItem.modal_visibility;">Request</a>
```

Comment: If i understand correctly, on click you are changing modal visibility in client's front view and then redirecting to language/zh. State of client's view will be reset after loading of the new page, so it's normal that it doesn't keep the visibility state.

Comment: @StewieSWS how do I keep the visibility state?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to put it into a function:

```
function make() {
   return (xtenderSearchItem.modal_visibility = ! xtenderSearchItem.modal_visibility)}
```

and then:

```
<a href="language/{{ 'zh' }}" onclick="make()">Request</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. I think it has something to do with laravel routes and controllers